# logrotate create null bytes on log file after rotate python log file

Tags: python, logrotate

I have the following logrotate.conf:

```
/path/to/my/file.log {
    weekly
    copytruncate
    rotate 5
    size 25
    nocompress
    sharedscripts
}
```

And I have the following bash script that execute my python:

```
python /app/myscript.py >> /path/to/my/file.log 2>&1&
```

After the logrotate run its create file.log with null bytes on begin, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use postrotate to remove null value from your log.

```
/path/to/my/file.log {
    weekly
    copytruncate
    rotate 5
    size 25
    nocompress
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
       sed -i -e 's/\o00//g' "$1"
    endscript

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your file is handled by a process
The 'sed' comman will broke the fs entry for the origina file

and your process will write to a deleted file !!

> ll -i  /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> 33554504 -rwxrwxr-x 1 usrcot17 cot 15957988 May 11 13:56 /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log

> grep -l    -P '\x00' /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> ll /proc/121203/fd/ | grep  jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> lrwx------ 1 usrcot17 cot 64 May 11 02:09 210 -> /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> lrwx------ 1 usrcot17 cot 64 May 11 02:09 75 -> /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> sed -i -e 's/\o00//g' /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> ll -i  /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> 33554503 -rwxrwxr-x 1 usrcot17 cot 832371 May 11 13:57 /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> grep -l    -P '\x00' /var/log/tomcat/17/jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> ll /proc/121203/fd/ | grep  jcxu11r2d2_log4j.log
> ll /proc/121203/fd/ | grep  deleted
> lrwx------ 1 usrcot17 cot 64 May 11 02:09 210 -> /var/log/tomcat/17/sedzP6J1h (deleted)
> lrwx------ 1 usrcot17 cot 64 May 11 02:09 75 -> /var/log/tomcat/17/sedzP6J1h (deleted)

the null chars are due to a buffered write from your process
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/135193

The only "good" solution i found at the moment is to let log rotation at the applicative process initiative